# Вставить swf в андроид приложение

Tags: phonegap, android, flash

С помощью phonegap написано приложение.
Вставляю swf

```
 <div data-role="page" id="for_virtual" data-theme="b"  data-add-back-btn="true">
 <div data-role="header" >

    <h1>Виртуаль</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" >  
    <div id="virtual">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="elabuga.swf" height="100%">
  <param name="movie" value="ment" />
 </object>
    </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

в эклипсе добавил

```
  super.init();
  super.appView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Но не отображается флэш. Что еще нужно сделать? флэш плеер на телефоне установлен.

Comment: Flash же свёрнут для Android, какой вообще смысл его куда-то пытаться встроить?

Answer (score 1):

А смысл встраивать?

Лагать будет очень жутко, до невозможности.

Тем более, как я понял HTML5 на андроид. Сам делал, на айпаде все летало, а на Гэлекси Таб 2 очень сильно лагало.

Comment: Тогда может ссылку в браузер дать?

Comment: айпад флэш воспроизводит что ли

Comment: И если делал, поясни как. Охота поэксперементировать